# Insert Java.sql.Date into Derby Database

Tags: java, sql, derby, embedded-database

I am trying to insert a date object into the database but it says im trying to insert an Integer. Here is my code:

```
public void insertAssignment(long studentId, String newAssignment, int ptsTotal, int ptsRecieved, String category, Date dueDate, String term, int yr) {
    java.sql.Date temp = new java.sql.Date(dueDate.getTime());
    try{
        s.execute("INSERT INTO Assignments " +
                  "VALUES (" + studentId + ",'" + newAssignment + "'," + ptsTotal +
                  "," + ptsRecieved + ",'" + category + "'," + temp
                  + ",'" + term + "'," + yr + ")");
        System.out.println("Assignment inserted.");
    }
    catch(SQLException error){
        System.err.println("Unable to insertAssignment.");
        error.printStackTrace(System.err);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

My error: 
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Columns of type 'DATE' cannot hold values of type 'INTEGER'.

Comment: It is because the column matching your date column is actually an int value. Also use PreparedStatement. In your sql add the column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, use a prepared statement instead and use a setter.

Currently you flatten your date to a string value (which needs to be in the right format for the database for this to work) and lose that it is a date so the database needs to parse it.  You avoid this using the prepared statement.